# Application logging in weblogic 12c messed up after upgrading Jdeveloper from 12.1.2 to 12.1.3

Tags: java, logging, weblogic, jdeveloper

We recently upgraded JDeveloper from 12.1.2 to 12.3. Application logging has messed up since then. App works but the log is filled up with below messages. Any help on this is highly appreciated.

```
<Dec 17, 2014 2:06:37 PM EST> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101394> 
<The exception "The request content-type is not a multipart/form-data" occurred 
when processing getParameter or getParameterValues from a multipart value of a    
ServletRequest.> 

<Dec 17, 2014 2:06:39 PM EST> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101394> <The exception "The   
request content-type is not a multipart/form-data" occurred when processing 
getParameter or getParameterValues from a multipart value of a ServletRequest.> 

<Dec 17, 2014 2:06:39 PM EST> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101394> <The exception "The 
request content-type is not a multipart/form-data" occurred when processing 
getParameter or getParameterValues from a multipart value of a ServletRequest.> 

<Dec 17, 2014 2:06:39 PM EST> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101394> <The exception "The 
request content-type is not a multipart/form-data" occurred when processing 
getParameter or getParameterValues from a multipart value of a ServletRequest.> 

<Dec 17, 2014 2:06:39 PM EST> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101394> <The exception "The 
request content-type is not a multipart/form-data" occurred when processing 
getParameter or getParameterValues from a multipart value of a ServletRequest.> 

<Dec 17, 2014 2:06:40 PM EST> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101394> <The exception "The 
 request content-type is not a multipart/form-data" occurred when processing 
getParameter or getParameterValues from a multipart value of a ServletRequest.> 

<Dec 17, 2014 2:06:40 PM EST> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101394> <The exception "The 
request content-type is not a multipart/form-data" occurred when processing 
getParameter or getParameterValues from a multipart value of a ServletRequest.> 

<Dec 17, 2014 2:06:40 PM EST> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101394> <The exception "The 
request content-type is not a multipart/form-data" occurred when processing 
getParameter or getParameterValues from a multipart value of a ServletRequest.> 

<Dec 17, 2014 2:06:40 PM EST> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101394> <The exception "The 
request content-type is not a multipart/form-data" occurred when processing 
getParameter or getParameterValues from a multipart value of a ServletRequest.> 

<Dec 17, 2014 2:06:40 PM EST> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101394> <The exception "The 
request content-type is no
```

Comment: Are there any other errors? What problems is it causing? Hard to tell what you are asking.

Comment: There are few database related exceptions, I am suspecting they are caused by Derby, which I don't use. The app works fine but does not print any application log. Here is the db exception.                    `weblogic.application.ModuleException: weblogic.common.ResourceException: weblogic.common.ResourceException: Could not create pool connection for datasource 'LocalSvcTblDataSource'. The DBMS driver exception was: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.`

Comment: Are you using log4j? There is nothing in your exceptions to help debug why you are having logging problems

Comment: Do you use wls 12.1 3? ADF? The right runtime? Have you checked the descriptors after the migration?

Comment: Yes I am using 10g4j and wls 12.1.3. No ADF. The app is java, EE, Spring and JPA app. The app was not coming up after the upgrade; was erroring out on Spring. I had to add spring classes in weblogic.xml to resolve the problem. Other than that have not made any changes. I am using spring 3.1.

Comment: I am also seeing the same message for every request. When using 12.1.3. The post messages have Content-type set to: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8 not sure why this needs a warning log?

Answer (score 4):

there is a bug filed for this in Oracle Support site
"Bug 19483893 : WHEN MULTIPARTCONFIG SUPPORT IT'S ENABLED, FILLS LOG WITH WARNING MESSAGES"

"So in summary, issue relates only to the massive warning messages appearing
on log. There is no broken functionality at all with any patch. Just seems to
be that some piece of code added an extra warning message which was not
previously part of the product, which causes issues for customers."

It seems that there is no resolution for that, apart from ignoring (or you can apply a log filter at server logging framework level)

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same `<Warning>` on weblogic server 12.1.3 and primefaces 5.1.x JSF webapplication.
WebApp has no errors. It is working with no problems.
On wls 12.1.2 there are no such Warnings.

Comment: I am going to upgrade my spring and log4j libraries. If that does not help then I will open a support ticket with Oracle.

Comment: I am also going to try reinstalling JDeveloper!

Comment: @ Bruno. Do you see application exceptions, errors in the log?

Comment: Thanks Bruno. What I meant to ask was do you see application logs? That is broken for me.

Comment: Yes, application log of my local wls server (without JDevelover) is available and marks `code` <WL-101394> <The exception "The request content-type is not a multipart/form-data" occurred when" `code` very often.

Comment: Oracle issued a patch to fix the issue.

Comment: could you the oracles issue number?

Comment: Do you have a reference to the patch?